# QT Designer: Set Qdoublespinbox suffix

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I making a Gui with Qt Designer, I'm using a double spin box and I need to append a suffix to display a unit ("miliVolts").

I'm trying to set it in the Qt creator.

[image]

I don't want to use the code to do it:
     sb->setSuffix(" km");

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter the value of suffix in the column in front of "suffix", it's editable.